# XNA: Adding a Nuclex Screen to GuiManager.screen breaks 3d rendering

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to set up an extremely simple XNA game with a 3d terrain and some 2d GUI objects on top. I chose Nuclex since that seems to be one of the few 2d GUIs that's currently active.

My problem: adding a Nuclex "screen" class to my game results in the 3d terrain and lines drawn on top of it to screw up -- I have three layers of 3d objects: terrain, a wireframe outline of the terrain and some "routes" that hug the terrain. With the screen added, the routes that are partially-submerged into the terrain appear entirely on top of the terrain, and the wireframe grid appears thicker.

This is the tail-end of my Game.Initialize method, as made by following the sample on the Nuclex GuiManager page:

```
    InputManager im = new InputManager();

    IGraphicsDeviceService igds = Nuclex.Graphics.GraphicsDeviceServiceHelper.MakeDummyGraphicsDeviceService(GraphicsDevice); 
    gui = new GuiManager(igds, im);
    gui.Initialize();

    Viewport vp = GraphicsDevice.Viewport; 
    Screen main_screen = new Screen(vp.Width, vp.Height);
    //main_screen.
    this.gui.Screen = main_screen; 
    main_screen.Desktop.Bounds = new UniRectangle(
        new UniScalar(0.1f, 0.0f), new UniScalar(0.1f, 0.0f), // x and y
        new UniScalar(0.8f, 0.0f), new UniScalar(0.8f, 0.0f) // width and height
    );

    LabelControl text = new LabelControl("hello");
    text.Bounds = new UniRectangle(10, 10, 200, 30);

    main_screen.Desktop.Children.Add(text);

    Components.Add(gui);

    base.Initialize();
```

So, any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that Nuclex messes up your render states on Render? Maybe making sure to save states before to render GUI, then restore them after?

Comment: In order to do rendering, Nuclex should be added to the Game's components (at Components.Add(gui)), according to the docs -- so that doesn't give me any handle on the draw order. You're right in that it is almost certainly messing around with the settings of the graphicsDevice that is passed to it.

However, if I remove the Components.Add line and instead manually call gui.Draw in my Game.Draw function, the same problem still occurs, even if I put the gui.Draw call in *after* all of the other elements have been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so thanks to catflier who pointed me in the direction of render states, I fixed the problem:
* First, "RenderState" is an XNA3 term; XNA4 simply allows a few state flags directly on the GraphicsDevice object.
* The problem is that Nuclex is secretly setting the GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState and leaving it instead of restoring it to its previous value after use (naughty!!).
* So the solution is, at the top of your Draw method, to add a line like so:

```
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
```

Comment: Good to know that it works, Ideally you should also do it for GraphicsDevice.BlendState and GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState , just to make sure.